PhpSpreadsheet poner valor de un regtistro repetido de MYSQL en una columna de EXCEL previamente insertada
edito el codigo ya que logre insertar los registros MYSQL en Excel, y poner los datos de DESCRIPCIOn y DIA (si tipoActividad=1) y NOMBRE_SESION y DIA (si tipoActividad=2) en su sitio (sin que se repita todo su rango, pero el problema es que no logro resolver el tema que encuentre una celda con DNI repetido y ponga el registro actual en la siguiente celda correspondiente (por ejemplo: si anteriormente AE(nombre_sesion) y AF(dia) se lleno con un registro, al encontrar otra vez el doc_identidad correspondiente a esa fila, debería ubicarle ya en la celda AG(para nombre_sesion) y AH(dia).
aqui les dejo la tabla de MYSQL:
CREATE TABLE `detalle_reporte_mensual` (
  `id_detalle_reporte_mensual` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `id_reporte_mensual` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `id_paciente` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `planificacion_intervencion` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `tipo_intervencion` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `id_grupo_especifico` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `otros_relevantes` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_regimen` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `id_etapa` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `id_descripciones` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `dia_actividades` int(2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '01-30',
  `id_sesiones` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `observaciones` text DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'TEMAS',
  `cambio_PPI` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

Entonces en php creo la consulta para listar los registros de esa tabla:
he vuelto a cambiar el código hoy(04/11/2024) php para que sea orientado a objetos y tengo problemas para implementar la función obtenerValor , ya que si obtiene todos los valores de las celdas: C hasta AD, pero las celdas AE hasta la AQ no les inserta. a ver si alguien ahi me da una mano:
<?php
include("conexion.php"); // Asumiendo que tu conexión está configurada aquí
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
$objCon = new Conexion();

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate;
use Monolog\Level;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler;

// Configuración básica para mostrar todos los errores
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

//Guardando el tipo_actividad
// $tipoActividad=2;

class Registro
{
    public $interno;
 
    
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->interno = [
            'doc_identidad' => $data['documento_identidad'],
            'datos_adicionales' => [
                'nombre_completo' => $data['apellidos_nombres_interno'],
                'fecha_ingreso' => $data['fecha_ingreso'],
                'fecha_nac' => $data['fecha_nacimiento'],
                'discapacidad' => $data['discapacidad'],
                'planificacion_intervencion' => $data['planificacion_intervencion'],
                'tipo_intervencion' => $data['tipo_intervencion'],
                'grupo_especifico' => $data['grupo_especifico'],
                'otros_relevantes' => $data['otros_relevantes'],
                'regimen' => $data['regimen'],
                'etapa' => $data['etapa'],
                'pabellon' => $data['pabellon'],
                'descripcion' => mb_convert_encoding($data['descripcion'], "UTF-8"),
                'dia' => $data['dia'],
                'nombre_sesion' => mb_convert_encoding($data['nombre_sesion'], "UTF-8"),
                'profesional' => $data['datos_profesional'],
                'observaciones' => $data['observaciones']
                // ... otros datos adicionales

            ]
        ];


    }
}

class GeneradorReporteExcel
{
    private $spreadsheet;
    private $sheet;
    private $logger;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $this->sheet = $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

        //Logs
        $this->logger = new Logger('my_app');
        $this->logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(__DIR__ . '/reportes/debug.log', Level::Debug));
        // $this->logger->info('My logger is now ready');
        $this->logger->pushHandler(new FirePHPHandler());
    }

    private function obtenerValor($registro, $columna, $fila, $tipoActividad)
    {
        switch ($columna) {
            case 'C':
                return $registro->interno['doc_identidad'];
            case 'D':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['nombre_completo'];
            case 'E':
                return 'MASCULINO';
            case 'F':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['fecha_ingreso'];
            case 'G':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['fecha_nac'];
            case 'H':
                // Obtener la celda de fecha de nacimiento (suponiendo que 'G2' es relativa)
                $celdaFechaNacimiento = 'G' . $fila; // Ajusta la fila según tu lógica
                // Construir la fórmula completa
                $formula = "=(NOW()-" . $celdaFechaNacimiento . ")/365-0.5";
                return $formula;
            case 'I':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['discapacidad'];
            case 'J':
                //planificacion d ela intervencion
                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['planificacion_intervencion'] == 1) {
                    $planificacion_intervencion = "PTI_EN_PROCESO";
                }

                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['planificacion_intervencion'] == 2) {
                    $planificacion_intervencion = "PTI_P";
                }

                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['planificacion_intervencion'] == 3) {
                    $planificacion_intervencion = "PTI_S";
                }
                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['planificacion_intervencion'] == 4) {
                    $planificacion_intervencion = "POPE_ANTIGUA";
                }
                return $planificacion_intervencion;
            case 'K':
                //tipo de intervencion
                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['tipo_intervencion'] == 1) {
                    $tipo_intervencion = "INDUCCION_Y_ADAPTACION_AL_REGIMEN_PENITENCIARIO";
                }
                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['tipo_intervencion'] == 2) {
                    $tipo_intervencion = "INTERVENCION_GENERAL";
                }
                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['tipo_intervencion'] == 3) {
                    $tipo_intervencion = "INTERVENCION_ESPECIALIZADA";
                }
                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['tipo_intervencion'] == 4) {
                    $tipo_intervencion = "PROGRAMACIÓN_SOBRE_NECESIDADES_DE_INTERVENCIÓN_COMPLEMENTARIA";
                }
                return $tipo_intervencion;
            case 'L':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['grupo_especifico'];
            case 'M':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['otros_relevantes'];
            case 'N':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['regimen'];
            case 'O':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['etapa'];
            case 'P':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['pabellon'];
            case 'Q':
            case 'S':
            case 'U':
            case 'W':
            case 'Y':
            case 'AA':
            case 'AC':
                if ($tipoActividad === 1) {
                    $descripcion=$registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['descripcion']; // O el campo de descripción que corresponda
                } else {
                    $descripcion='';
                }
                return $descripcion;
            case 'R':
            case 'T':
            case 'V':
            case 'X':
            case 'Z':
            case 'AB':
            case 'AD':
                if ($tipoActividad === 1) {
                    $dia=$registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['dia']; // O el campo de descripción que corresponda
                } else {
                    $dia='';
                }
                return $dia;
            case 'AE':
            case 'AG':
            case 'AI':
            case 'AK':
            case 'AM':
                if ($tipoActividad == 2) {
                    // Manejar el caso cuando tipoActividad es 2 (si aplica)
                    $nombre_sesion=$registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['nombre_sesion']; // O el campo de nombre de sesión que corresponda
                } else {
                    $nombre_sesion='';
                }
                return $nombre_sesion;

            case 'AF':
            case 'AH':
            case 'AJ':
            case 'AL':
            case 'AN':
                if ($tipoActividad == 2) {
                    // Manejar el caso cuando tipoActividad no es 1 ni 2
                    $dia=$registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['dia']; // O el campo de nombre de sesión que corresponda
                } else {
                    $dia='';
                }
                return $dia;

            case 'AO':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['profesional'];
            case 'AP':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['observaciones'];
                // case 'AQ':
                //     return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['nombre_completo'];
            default:
                return '';
        }
    }



    private function escribirEnCelda($columna, $fila, $valor)
    {
        // $this->logger->debug("Escribiendo $valor en la celda $columna$fila");
        // $this->sheet->setCellValue($columna . $fila, $valor);

        try {
            // $this->logger->info('My logger is now ready');
            // $this->logger->debug("Escribiendo $valor en la celda $columna$fila");
            $this->sheet->setCellValue($columna . $fila, $valor);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error("Error al escribir en la celda: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    private function getRangoColumnas($tipoActividad, $esNuevoRegistro)
    {
        if($tipoActividad==1){
        return $esNuevoRegistro ? ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD','AO','AP'] : ['O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD'];
        }else{
            return $esNuevoRegistro ?  ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH','AI','AJ','AK','AL','AM','AN','AO','AP'] : ['AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH','AI','AJ','AK','AL','AM','AN'];
        }
    }

    private function buscarFilaPorDni($dni)
    {
        // Suponiendo que el DNI está en la columna C
        $highestRow = $this->sheet->getHighestRow();
        $this->logger->debug("Cuantas filas hay?: $highestRow");
        for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
            
            if ($this->sheet->getCell('C' . $row)->getValue() === $dni) {
                // $this->logger->debug("Fila del archivo Excel: $this->sheet->getCell('C' . $row)->getValue() == DNI: $dni");
                $tipoActividad = 2; //$this->sheet->getCell('A' . $row)->getValue(); // Suponiendo que el tipo de actividad está en la columna A
                $rangoColumnas = $this->getRangoColumnas($tipoActividad, false);
                return [
                    'fila' => $row,
                    'rangoColumnas' => $rangoColumnas
                ];
            }
            // $this->logger->debug("DNI EXCEL: $this->sheet->getCell('C' . $row)->getValue()  NO ES IGUAL A DNI SQL: $dni");
            
        }
       
        return false;
     
    }

 private function crearNuevaFila($fila, $registro, $rangoColumnas, $tipoActividad,$esNuevoRegistro) {
    $columnaIndex = 0; // Inicializamos el índice de columna

    foreach ($rangoColumnas as $columna) {
        if($tipoActividad=2 && $esNuevoRegistro==true){
            if($columnaIndex==16 || $columnaIndex==17 || $columnaIndex==18 || $columnaIndex==19 || $columnaIndex==20 || $columnaIndex==21 || $columnaIndex==22){
                // $this->logger->debug("columnaIndex: $columnaIndex - Pertenece a la columna: $columna ---> NO SE REGISTRO");
                continue;
            }
        }else{

            $valor = $this->obtenerValor($registro, $columna, $fila, $tipoActividad);
            $this->escribirEnCelda($columna, $fila, $valor);
            // $this->logger->debug("columnaIndex: $columnaIndex - Pertenece a la columna: $columna ---> valor = $valor ");
            $columnaIndex++;
       }
        
      
        
        // $this->logger->debug("columnaIndex: $columnaIndex - Pertenece a la columna: $columna[$columnaIndex] ---> valor = $valor ");
        // Validación adicional: Verificar si el valor es una cadena vacía o null
        // if (!empty($valor)) {
        //     $this->escribirEnCelda($columna, $fila, $valor);
        //     $columnaIndex++; // Incrementamos el índice solo si escribimos un valor
             
        //     // Si es un nuevo registro y ya escribimos los dos primeros valores, salimos del bucle
        // for($columnaIndex=15;$columnaIndex<24;$columnaIndex++) {
        //         continue 2;
        //     }
        //     // $columnaIndex = 23; // Ajustar el índice para la siguiente columna (AG)
        // }
    }
}
 

    private function actualizarFila($fila, $registro,  $rangosAdicionales=true)
    {
        $tipoActividad = 2; //$registro->tipo_actividad;
        $rangoColumnas = $this->getRangoColumnas($tipoActividad, false);

        // Encontrar la primera columna vacía en el rango adicional
        $columnaVacía = null;
        foreach ($rangosAdicionales[$tipoActividad] as $columna) {
            if ($this->sheet->getCell($columna . $fila)->getValue() === null) {
                $columnaVacía = $columna;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Si se encontró una columna vacía, escribir el valor
        if ($columnaVacía) {
            $columnaIndex = array_search($columnaVacía, $rangoColumnas);
            $valor = $registro->datos_adicionales[$columnaIndex]; // $this->obtenerValor($registro, $columna);
            $this->escribirEnCelda($columnaVacía, $fila, $valor);
        }
    }



    public function generarReporte($registros, $rutaArchivo, $formatoArchivo)
    {
        // Cargar el archivo de formato
        $this->spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($formatoArchivo);
        $this->sheet = $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

        $fila = 2;

        foreach ($registros as $registro) {
            $tipoActividad = 2; //$registro->datos_adicionales['tipo_intervencion'];

            // Determinar si es un nuevo registro o no ---> OK!
            if ($this->buscarFilaPorDni($registro->interno['doc_identidad'])) {
                $rangoColumnas = $this->getRangoColumnas($tipoActividad, false); // Registro existente
            } else {
                $rangoColumnas = $this->getRangoColumnas($tipoActividad, true); // Nuevo registro
            }


            $dni = $registro->interno['doc_identidad'];
            $filaExistente = $this->buscarFilaPorDni($dni);

            if ($filaExistente) {
                // $this->logger->info('My logger is now ready');
                $this->actualizarFila($filaExistente, $registro, $rangoColumnas);
            } else {
                $this->crearNuevaFila($fila, $registro, $rangoColumnas, $tipoActividad,true);
                $fila++;
            }
        }

        // Guardar el archivo Excel
        $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($this->spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
        $writer->save($rutaArchivo);
        return "Archivo Generado con Exito!";
    }

    // ... (resto de los métodos)
}

// ... (tu código de conexión a la base de datos y consulta SQL)
$id_reporte = 1;
// Consulta SQL
$sql = "SELECT I.doc_identidad AS 'DOCUMENTO_IDENTIDAD',
                            I.ape_nombres AS 'APELLIDOS_NOMBRES_INTERNO',
                            I.fecha_ingreso AS 'FECHA_INGRESO',
                            I.fecha_nacimiento AS 'FECHA_NACIMIENTO',
                            I.discapacidad AS 'discapacidad',

                            DET.planificacion_intervencion AS 'PLANIFICACION_INTERVENCION',
                            DET.tipo_intervencion AS 'TIPO_INTERVENCION',
                            GRUP.nombre_grupo_especifico AS 'GRUPO_ESPECIFICO',
                            DET.otros_relevantes AS 'OTROS_RELEVANTES',
                            REG.nombre_regimen AS 'REGIMEN',
                            ETP.nombre_etapa AS 'ETAPA',
                            I.pab_celda_etapa AS 'PABELLON',
                            DESCRIP.nombre_descripciones AS 'DESCRIPCION',
                            DET.dia_actividades AS 'dia',
                            SES.nombre_sesiones AS 'nombre_sesion',
                            CONCAT(U.ape_paterno,' ',U.ape_materno,' ',U.nombres) AS 'DATOS_PROFESIONAL',
                            DET.observaciones AS 'OBSERVACIONES',
                            DET.cambio_PTIP_PTIS AS 'PTI_P_PTI_S'
                        FROM reportes_mensuales REP
                        INNER JOIN detalle_reporte_mensual DET ON REP.id_reporte_mensual=DET.id_reporte_mensual
                        INNER JOIN grupo_especifico GRUP ON DET.id_grupo_especifico=GRUP.id_grupo_especifico
                        INNER JOIN internos I ON DET.id_interno=I.id_interno
                        INNER JOIN usuarios U ON REP.id_usuario=U.id_usuario
                        INNER JOIN regimen REG ON DET.id_regimen=REG.id_regimen
                        INNER JOIN etapa ETP ON DET.id_etapa=ETP.id_etapa
                        INNER JOIN descripciones DESCRIP ON DET.id_descripciones=DESCRIP.id_descripciones
                        INNER JOIN sessiones SES ON DET.id_sesiones=SES.id_sesiones

                        WHERE REP.id_reporte_mensual=:id_reporte"; // Tu consulta SQL completa

$rsDetalleReporte = $objCon->getConexion()->prepare($sql);
$rsDetalleReporte->bindParam(':id_reporte', $id_reporte, PDO::PARAM_INT);

if ($rsDetalleReporte->execute()) {
    $registros = [];
    while ($row = $rsDetalleReporte->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $registro = new Registro($row);
        $registros[] = $registro;
        // Imprimir los datos del registro para verificar
        // echo json_encode($registro)."<br>";
    }

    // Verificar si el array $registros está vacío
    if (empty($registros)) {
        echo "No se encontraron registros.";
    } else {
        // Generar el reporte
        $generador = new GeneradorReporteExcel();
        $generador->generarReporte($registros, 'reportes/reporte_actualizado.xlsx', 'reportes/FORMATO_SOCIAL.xlsx');
    }
} else {
    // Manejar errores en la ejecución de la consulta
    echo "Error al ejecutar la consulta: " . $rsDetalleReporte->errorInfo()[2];
}
?>

se agradece las respuestas !

no logro comprenderte del todo podrias ser mas especifico...

Bryro, Gracias por comentar lo que deseo en si es insertar datos de MYSQL a un Excel pero hay datos repetidos en MYSQL que deberían actualizarse en el archivo Excel esos datos son algunas columnas dependiendo del tipo_actividad, por ejemplo: tipo_actividad=1 entocnes rangoColumnas es [Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC,AD]  entonces deberia buscar la fila donde esta ese reigstro repetido MYSQL en Excel y ver si la celda Q,R esta llena actualizar la siguiente fila S con valor "descripcion" y T valor "dia" y asi con tipo_actividad=2 con su rango desde AE hasta AN con SESIONES_NAME y DIA.

Problema solucionado, para los que tengan un problema similar les comparto el código:
<?php
include("conexion.php"); // Asumiendo que tu conexión está configurada aquí
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
$objCon = new Conexion();

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate;
use Monolog\Level;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler;

// Configuración básica para mostrar todos los errores
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

//Guardando el tipo_actividad e id_reporte
$tipo_Actividad=$_POST['tipo_actividad'];
$id_reporte = $_POST['id_reporte'];

class Registro
{
    public $interno;
    
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->interno = [
            'doc_identidad' => $data['documento_identidad'],
            'datos_adicionales' => [
                'nombre_completo' => $data['apellidos_nombres_interno'],
                'fecha_ingreso' => $data['fecha_ingreso'],
                'fecha_nac' => $data['fecha_nacimiento'],
                'discapacidad' => $data['discapacidad'],
                'planificacion_intervencion' => $data['planificacion_intervencion'],
                'tipo_intervencion' => $data['tipo_intervencion'],
                'grupo_especifico' => $data['grupo_especifico'],
                'otros_relevantes' => $data['otros_relevantes'],
                'regimen' => $data['regimen'],
                'etapa' => $data['etapa'],
                'pabellon' => $data['pabellon'],
                'descripcion' => mb_convert_encoding($data['descripcion'], "UTF-8"),
                'dia' => $data['dia'],
                'nombre_sesion' => mb_convert_encoding($data['nombre_sesion'], "UTF-8"),
                'profesional' => $data['datos_profesional'],
                'observaciones' => $data['observaciones']
                // ... otros datos adicionales

            ]
        ];
        // $this->nombre_completo = $data['apellidos_nombres_interno'];



    }
}

class GeneradorReporteExcel
{
    private $spreadsheet;
    private $sheet;
    private $logger;
    

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $this->sheet = $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

        //Logs
        $this->logger = new Logger('my_app');
        $this->logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(__DIR__ . '/reportes/debug.log', Level::Debug));
        // $this->logger->info('My logger is now ready');
        $this->logger->pushHandler(new FirePHPHandler());
    }

    private function obtenerValor($registro, $columna, $fila, $tipoActividad)
    {
        switch ($columna) {
            case 'C':
                return $registro->interno['doc_identidad'];
            case 'D':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['nombre_completo'];
            case 'E':
                return 'MASCULINO';
            case 'F':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['fecha_ingreso'];
            case 'G':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['fecha_nac'];
            case 'H':
                // Obtener la celda de fecha de nacimiento (suponiendo que 'G2' es relativa)
                $celdaFechaNacimiento = 'G' . $fila; // Ajusta la fila según tu lógica
                // Construir la fórmula completa
                $formula = "=(NOW()-" . $celdaFechaNacimiento . ")/365-0.5";
                return $formula;
            case 'I':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['discapacidad'];
            case 'J':
                //planificacion d ela intervencion
                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['planificacion_intervencion'] == 1) {
                    $planificacion_intervencion = "PTI_EN_PROCESO";
                }

                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['planificacion_intervencion'] == 2) {
                    $planificacion_intervencion = "PTI_P";
                }

                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['planificacion_intervencion'] == 3) {
                    $planificacion_intervencion = "PTI_S";
                }
                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['planificacion_intervencion'] == 4) {
                    $planificacion_intervencion = "POPE_ANTIGUA";
                }
                return $planificacion_intervencion;
            case 'K':
                //tipo de intervencion
                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['tipo_intervencion'] == 1) {
                    $tipo_intervencion = "INDUCCION_Y_ADAPTACION_AL_REGIMEN_PENITENCIARIO";
                }
                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['tipo_intervencion'] == 2) {
                    $tipo_intervencion = "INTERVENCION_GENERAL";
                }
                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['tipo_intervencion'] == 3) {
                    $tipo_intervencion = "INTERVENCION_ESPECIALIZADA";
                }
                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['tipo_intervencion'] == 4) {
                    $tipo_intervencion = "PROGRAMACIÓN_SOBRE_NECESIDADES_DE_INTERVENCIÓN_COMPLEMENTARIA";
                }
                return $tipo_intervencion;
            case 'L':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['grupo_especifico'];
            case 'M':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['otros_relevantes'];
            case 'N':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['regimen'];
            case 'O':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['etapa'];
            case 'P':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['pabellon'];
            case 'Q':
            case 'S':
            case 'U':
            case 'W':
            case 'Y':
            case 'AA':
            case 'AC':
                if ($tipoActividad === 1) {
                    $descripcion=$registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['descripcion']; // O el campo de descripción que corresponda
                } else {
                    $descripcion='';
                }
                return $descripcion;
            case 'R':
            case 'T':
            case 'V':
            case 'X':
            case 'Z':
            case 'AB':
            case 'AD':
                if ($tipoActividad === 1) {
                    $dia=$registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['dia']; // O el campo de descripción que corresponda
                } else {
                    $dia='';
                }
                return $dia;
            case 'AE':
            case 'AG':
            case 'AI':
            case 'AK':
            case 'AM':
                if ($tipoActividad == 2) {
                    // Manejar el caso cuando tipoActividad es 2 (si aplica)
                    $nombre_sesion=$registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['nombre_sesion']; // O el campo de nombre de sesión que corresponda
                } else {
                    $nombre_sesion='';
                }
                return $nombre_sesion;

            case 'AF':
            case 'AH':
            case 'AJ':
            case 'AL':
            case 'AN':
                if ($tipoActividad == 2) {
                    // Manejar el caso cuando tipoActividad no es 1 ni 2
                    $dia=$registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['dia']; // O el campo de nombre de sesión que corresponda
                } else {
                    $dia='';
                }
                return $dia;

            case 'AO':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['profesional'];
            case 'AP':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['observaciones'];
                // case 'AQ':
                //     return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['nombre_completo'];
            default:
                return '';
        }
    }



    private function escribirEnCelda($columna, $fila, $valor)
    {
        // $this->logger->debug("Escribiendo $valor en la celda $columna$fila");
        // $this->sheet->setCellValue($columna . $fila, $valor);

        try {
            // $this->logger->info('My logger is now ready');
            // $this->logger->debug("Escribiendo $valor en la celda $columna$fila");
            $this->sheet->setCellValue($columna . $fila, $valor);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error("Error al escribir en la celda: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    private function getRangoColumnas($tipoActividad, $esNuevoRegistro)
    {
        if($tipoActividad==1){
        return $esNuevoRegistro ? ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD'] : ['O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD'];
        }else{
            return $esNuevoRegistro ?  ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH','AI','AJ','AK','AL','AM','AN','AO','AP'] : ['AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH','AI','AJ','AK','AL','AM','AN'];
        }
    }

    private function buscarFilaPorDni($dni)
    {
        // Suponiendo que el DNI está en la columna C
        $highestRow = $this->sheet->getHighestRow();
        // $this->logger->debug("Cuantas filas hay?: $highestRow");
        for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
            
            if ($this->sheet->getCell('C' . $row)->getValue() == $dni) {
                // $this->logger->debug("Fila del archivo Excel: $this->sheet->getCell('C' . $row)->getValue() == DNI: $dni");
                $tipoActividad = 2; //$this->sheet->getCell('A' . $row)->getValue(); // Suponiendo que el tipo de actividad está en la columna A
                $rangoColumnas = $this->getRangoColumnas($tipoActividad, false);
                return [
                    'fila' => $row,
                    'rangoColumnas' => $rangoColumnas
                ];
            }
            // $this->logger->debug("DNI EXCEL: $this->sheet->getCell('C' . $row)->getValue()  NO ES IGUAL A DNI SQL: $dni");
            
        }
       
        return false;
     
    }

 private function crearNuevaFila($fila, $registro, $rangoColumnas, $tipoActividad,$esNuevoRegistro) {
    $columnaIndex = 0; // Inicializamos el índice de columna

    foreach ($rangoColumnas as $columna) {
        if($tipoActividad=2 && $esNuevoRegistro==true){
            if($columnaIndex==16 || $columnaIndex==17 || $columnaIndex==18 || $columnaIndex==19 || $columnaIndex==20 || $columnaIndex==21 || $columnaIndex==22){
                // $this->logger->debug("columnaIndex: $columnaIndex - Pertenece a la columna: $columna ---> NO SE REGISTRO");
                continue;
            }
        }else{

       }
        
        $valor = $this->obtenerValor($registro, $columna, $fila, $tipoActividad);
        $this->escribirEnCelda($columna, $fila, $valor);
        // $this->logger->debug("columnaIndex: $columnaIndex - Pertenece a la columna: $columna ---> valor = $valor ");
        $columnaIndex++;
    }
}
 

    private function actualizarFila($fila, $registro,  $rangosAdicionales)
    {
        $tipoActividad = 2; //$registro->tipo_actividad;

        // Encontrar la primera columna vacía en el rango adicional
         $columnaVacia = null;

    //    $this->logger->debug("Rango: $rangosAdicionales[$tipoActividad]");
         foreach ($rangosAdicionales as $columna) {

             if ($this->sheet->getCell( $columna. $fila)->getValue() === null) {
                 $columnaVacia =  $columna;
                //  $this->logger->debug("Columna Vacia: $columnaVacia");
                 break;
             }
          }

        // Si se encontró una columna vacía, escribir el valor
         if ($columnaVacia) {
            //  $columnaIndex = array_search($columnaVacia, $rangosAdicionales);
            //  $this->logger->debug("ColumnaIndex: $columnaIndex ");
            $sesion =$registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['nombre_sesion']; // $this->obtenerValor($registro, $columna);
            $this->escribirEnCelda($columnaVacia, $fila, $sesion);
            //aumentando en 1 para el día
            $columnaVacia++;
            $dia=$registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['dia'];
            $this->escribirEnCelda($columnaVacia, $fila, $dia);
         }
    }



    public function generarReporte($registros, $rutaArchivo, $formatoArchivo,$tipoActividad)
    {
        // Cargar el archivo de formato
        $this->spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($formatoArchivo);
        $this->sheet = $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

        $fila = 2;

        foreach ($registros as $registro) {
            $tipoActividad = $tipoActividad; //$registro->datos_adicionales['tipo_intervencion'];

            // Determinar si es un nuevo registro o no ---> OK!
            if ($this->buscarFilaPorDni($registro->interno['doc_identidad'])) {
                $rangoColumnas = $this->getRangoColumnas($tipoActividad, false); // Registro existente
                //hayando la fila repetida
                // $dni = $registro->interno['doc_identidad'];
                 $resultadoBusqueda=$this->buscarFilaPorDni($registro->interno['doc_identidad'])['fila'];
                    //  $this->logger->debug("FILA REPETIDA: ".$resultadoBusqueda);
                // if (is_array($resultadoBusqueda)) {
                //     $filaExistente =  $resultadoBusqueda[0];//$this->buscarFilaPorDni($dni)[0];
                //     $this->logger->debug("FILA REPETIDA: $filaExistente");
                // }
                $this->actualizarFila($resultadoBusqueda, $registro, $rangoColumnas);
                //  $this->logger->debug("BuscarFilaDNI devuelve estos valores: ".json_encode($this->buscarFilaPorDni($registro->interno['doc_identidad'])));
            } else {
                $rangoColumnas = $this->getRangoColumnas($tipoActividad, true); // Nuevo registro
                $this->crearNuevaFila($fila, $registro, $rangoColumnas, $tipoActividad,true);
                $fila++;
                // $this->logger->debug("BuscarFilaDNI devuelve estos valores: ".$this->buscarFilaPorDni($registro->interno['doc_identidad']));
            }
        }

        // Guardar el archivo Excel
        $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($this->spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
        $writer->save($rutaArchivo);
    }

}


// Consulta SQL
$sql = "SELECT I.doc_identidad AS 'DOCUMENTO_IDENTIDAD',
                            I.ape_nombres AS 'APELLIDOS_NOMBRES_INTERNO',
                            I.fecha_ingreso AS 'FECHA_INGRESO',
                            I.fecha_nacimiento AS 'FECHA_NACIMIENTO',
                            I.discapacidad AS 'discapacidad',

                            DET.planificacion_intervencion AS 'PLANIFICACION_INTERVENCION',
                            DET.tipo_intervencion AS 'TIPO_INTERVENCION',
                            GRUP.nombre_grupo_especifico AS 'GRUPO_ESPECIFICO',
                            DET.otros_relevantes AS 'OTROS_RELEVANTES',
                            REG.nombre_regimen AS 'REGIMEN',
                            ETP.nombre_etapa AS 'ETAPA',
                            I.pab_celda_etapa AS 'PABELLON',
                            DESCRIP.nombre_descripciones AS 'DESCRIPCION',
                            DET.dia_actividades AS 'dia',
                            SES.nombre_sesiones AS 'nombre_sesion',
                            CONCAT(U.ape_paterno,' ',U.ape_materno,' ',U.nombres) AS 'DATOS_PROFESIONAL',
                            DET.observaciones AS 'OBSERVACIONES',
                            DET.cambio_PTIP_PTIS AS 'PTI_P_PTI_S'
                        FROM reportes_mensuales REP
                        INNER JOIN detalle_reporte_mensual DET ON REP.id_reporte_mensual=DET.id_reporte_mensual
                        INNER JOIN grupo_especifico GRUP ON DET.id_grupo_especifico=GRUP.id_grupo_especifico
                        INNER JOIN internos I ON DET.id_interno=I.id_interno
                        INNER JOIN usuarios U ON REP.id_usuario=U.id_usuario
                        INNER JOIN regimen REG ON DET.id_regimen=REG.id_regimen
                        INNER JOIN etapa ETP ON DET.id_etapa=ETP.id_etapa
                        INNER JOIN descripciones DESCRIP ON DET.id_descripciones=DESCRIP.id_descripciones
                        INNER JOIN sessiones SES ON DET.id_sesiones=SES.id_sesiones

                        WHERE REP.id_reporte_mensual=:id_reporte"; // Tu consulta SQL completa

$rsDetalleReporte = $objCon->getConexion()->prepare($sql);
$rsDetalleReporte->bindParam(':id_reporte', $id_reporte, PDO::PARAM_INT);

if ($rsDetalleReporte->execute()) {
    $registros = [];
    while ($row = $rsDetalleReporte->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $registro = new Registro($row);
        $registros[] = $registro;

        // Imprimir los datos del registro para verificar
        // echo json_encode($registro)."<br>";
    }

    // Verificar si el array $registros está vacío
    if (empty($registros)) {
        echo "No se encontraron registros.";
    } else {
        // Generar el reporte
        $generador = new GeneradorReporteExcel();
        $generador->generarReporte($registros, 'reportes/reporte_actualizado.xlsx', 'reportes/FORMATO_SOCIAL.xlsx',$tipo_Actividad);
    }
} else {
    // Manejar errores en la ejecución de la consulta
    echo "Error al ejecutar la consulta: " . $rsDetalleReporte->errorInfo()[2];
}
?>


puedes hacerlo asi:
agre algunas mejoras para la legibilidad.
<?php
include("conexion.php"); 
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate;
use Monolog\Level;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler;

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

class Registro
{
    public $paciente;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->paciente = [
            'doc_identidad' => $data['documento_identidad'] ?? '',
            'datos_adicionales' => [
                'nombre_completo' => $data['apellidos_nombres_paciente'] ?? '',
                'fecha_ingreso' => $data['fecha_ingreso'] ?? '',
                'fecha_nac' => $data['fecha_nacimiento'] ?? '',
                'discapacidad' => $data['discapacidad'] ?? '',
                'planificacion_intervencion' => $data['planificacion_intervencion'] ?? '',
                'tipo_intervencion' => $data['tipo_intervencion'] ?? '',
                'grupo_especifico' => $data['grupo_especifico'] ?? '',
                'otros_relevantes' => $data['otros_relevantes'] ?? '',
                'regimen' => $data['regimen'] ?? '',
                'etapa' => $data['etapa'] ?? '',
                'pabellon' => $data['pabellon'] ?? '',
                'descripcion' => mb_convert_encoding($data['descripcion'] ?? '', "UTF-8"),
                'dia' => $data['dia'] ?? '',
                'nombre_sesion' => mb_convert_encoding($data['nombre_sesion'] ?? '', "UTF-8"),
                'observaciones' => $data['observaciones'] ?? ''
            ]
        ];
    }
}

class GeneradorReporteExcel
{
    private $spreadsheet;
    private $sheet;
    private $logger;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $this->sheet = $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

        // Configuración de logs
        $this->logger = new Logger('my_app');
        $this->logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(__DIR__ . '/reportes/debug.log', Level::Debug));
        $this->logger->pushHandler(new FirePHPHandler());
    }

    private function getPlanificacionIntervencion($planificacion)
    {
        $mapa = [
            1 => "PTI_EN_PROCESO",
            2 => "PTI_P",
            3 => "PTI_S",
            4 => "POPE_ANTIGUA"
        ];
        return $mapa[$planificacion] ?? '';
    }

    private function getTipoIntervencion($tipo)
    {
        $mapa = [
            1 => "INDUCCION_Y_ADAPTACION_AL_REGIMEN_PENITENCIARIO",
            2 => "INTERVENCION_GENERAL",
            3 => "INTERVENCION_ESPECIALIZADA",
            4 => "PROGRAMACIÓN_SOBRE_NECESIDADES_DE_INTERVENCIÓN_COMPLEMENTARIA"
        ];
        return $mapa[$tipo] ?? '';
    }

    private function obtenerValor($registro, $columna, $fila, $tipoActividad)
    {
        $datos = $registro->paciente['datos_adicionales'];
        switch ($columna) {
            case 'C': return $registro->paciente['doc_identidad'];
            case 'D': return $datos['nombre_completo'];
            case 'E': return 'MASCULINO';
            case 'F': return $datos['fecha_ingreso'];
            case 'G': return $datos['fecha_nac'];
            case 'H': return "=(NOW()-G$fila)/365-0.5";
            case 'I': return $datos['discapacidad'];
            case 'J': return $this->getPlanificacionIntervencion($datos['planificacion_intervencion']);
            case 'K': return $this->getTipoIntervencion($datos['tipo_intervencion']);
            case 'L': return $datos['grupo_especifico'];
            case 'M': return $datos['otros_relevantes'];
            case 'N': return $datos['regimen'];
            case 'O': return $datos['etapa'];
            case 'P': return $datos['pabellon'];
            case 'Q': case 'S': case 'U': case 'W': case 'Y': case 'AA': case 'AC':
                return $tipoActividad === 1 ? $datos['descripcion'] : '';
            case 'R': case 'T': case 'V': case 'X': case 'Z': case 'AB': case 'AD':
                return $tipoActividad === 1 ? $datos['dia'] : '';
            case 'AE': case 'AG': case 'AI': case 'AK': case 'AM':
                return $tipoActividad === 2 ? $datos['nombre_sesion'] : '';
            case 'AF': case 'AH': case 'AJ': case 'AL': case 'AN':
                return $tipoActividad === 2 ? $datos['dia'] : '';
            case 'AP': return $datos['observaciones'];
            default: return '';
        }
    }

    private function escribirEnCelda($columna, $fila, $valor)
    {
        try {
            $this->sheet->setCellValue($columna . $fila, $valor);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error("Error al escribir en la celda $columna$fila: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    private function crearNuevaFila($fila, $registro, $rangoColumnas, $tipoActividad)
    {
        foreach ($rangoColumnas as $columna) {
            $valor = $this->obtenerValor($registro, $columna, $fila, $tipoActividad);
            if (!empty($valor)) {
                if ($columna === 'H') {
                    $this->sheet->getStyle($columna . $fila)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0');
                }
                $this->escribirEnCelda($columna, $fila, $valor);
            }
        }
    }
}

ahora para utlizarlo seria:
<?php
require 'conexion.php';
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

$datosPacientes =  $objCon->getConexion()->prepare($sql);.
$generadorReporte = new GeneradorReporteExcel();

foreach ($datosPacientes as $data) {
    $registro = new Registro($data);
    $filaInfo = $generadorReporte->buscarFilaPorDni($data['documento_identidad']);

    if ($filaInfo) {
        // Si se encontró la fila, actualizamos la existente
        $generadorReporte->crearNuevaFila($filaInfo['fila'], $registro, $filaInfo['rangoColumnas'], 2);
    } else {
        // Si no se encontró la fila, creamos una nueva
        $nuevaFila = $generadorReporte->sheet->getHighestRow() + 1;
        $rangoColumnas = $generadorReporte->getRangoColumnas(1, true); // Cambia el tipo de actividad y esNuevoRegistro según sea necesario
        $generadorReporte->crearNuevaFila($nuevaFila, $registro, $rangoColumnas, 1);
    }
}

// Guardar el Excel
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($generadorReporte->spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save(__DIR__ . '/reporte.xlsx');

echo "Reporte generado.";


Buen día  @Bryro, parece que estas definiendo las clases en un archivo diferente porque si lo pongo en un solo archivo agregando (obviamente) la parte de la consulta SQL y el BindParam y el execute, me dice que no están definidas las funciones (que por cierto son private):es por eso que yo defini una funcion public generarReporte($registros, $rutaArchivo, $formatoArchivo), la verdad es que te agradezco tu respuesta, voy a probarla con mas calma ya que ando en apuros y  te aviso, ¿podrías hacerlo en un solo archivo (siguiente la estructura de mi código)? saludos!

una imagen del error:
http://imgfz.com/i/V5cS8Gl.png

cambiando las funciones a publicas y las dos propiedades de la clase generadorReporte igual a publicas se soluciono los errores, pero no es lo que se quiere del código, he editado mi nuevo código, donde registra todos los datos pero aun tengo el problema de que no detecta los registros repetidos en el Excel.
